# Can't pass textarea value to php variable

Tags: php, html, variables, textarea

I need to assign text of textarea tag to php variable. I try do it like this:

```
<form method="GET">
        <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="query">some string</textarea>
</form>

<?php
    $query = $_REQUEST['query'];
    echo $query; 
?>
```

But I'm getting

```
Notice: Undefined index: query in index.php on line _
```

What do I do wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You could also use AJAX to force post of your form and recuperate the value, which assume your php code will be located in another file to be called.

Comment: sidenote: don't forget to pick an answer below, if it did helped you kindly click the check mark on the left side of the answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this:

```
// add a submit button first...
 <input type="submit" name="submit">

 <?php
   if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
     // means submit clicked!

     $query = $_GET['query'];
     echo $query;

     print_r($_GET) // check the values of $_GET array..
   }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you're using the entire code inside the same page, it's normal for it to throw you that warning on page load.

Use `empty()` with a conditional statement for that form element.

```
if(!empty($_REQUEST['query'])){
$query = $_REQUEST['query'];
}
```

*Plus,* in conjunction with `empty()`, use `isset()` with a named submit button, as I've outlined below.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']) && !empty($_REQUEST['query']) ){
```

Plus, you will need to add some type of button to submit the data.

Either a `<button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>`

or an input type `<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">`

---

- Forms default to "self" if an action to a file isn't present.

Such as your `<form method="GET">`

Otherwise, split your form and PHP apart, and use `<form method="GET" action="handler.php">`

having the HTML form as one file, and the PHP in the other.

It would still be best to use `empty()` and `isset()` for either case.

Comment: Yup - this is basically due to a quirk of `<textarea>` elements in that they're not sent through with the form if they contain no data, unlike `<input type="text" ... />` so it's quite possible to have `$_REQUEST['query']` not set - hence the *undefined index* error.

Comment: As an aside : `isset($_REQUEST['query']) && !empty($_REQUEST['query'])` is slightly pointless because `empty()` checks whether a variable is set anyway - so you just need `!empty()`

Comment: @CD001 So, using `empty()` is better than `isset()` with just textarea form elements?

Comment: Doesn't make much odds, if a textarea element contains data it *will* be sent through, if it doesn't it won't - so `!empty()` and `isset()` will equate to the same thing - it's not possible (I don't think) to have `<textarea>` elements both set **and** empty.

Comment: @CD001 That makes sense. A tid bit of information about `<textarea>` I never knew about, thanks for that. I've modified my answer in relation to that.

Comment: thank you so much for the answer, Helpfull, but I accepted another's user answer because it just appered here first

Comment: @DrWifey You're welcome. Actually, the timestamp on my answer is before all the others `13:25:26`, but keep it the way you have it now, it's ok. I'm just glad you got your solution, *cheers*

Answer (score 1):

You need to post the form.

You are not posting it. This is the reason.

Add a new element `submit`

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to add a submit button to form and default form method will be get so no need to add method get

```
<form>
   <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="query">some string</textarea>
   <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

and for check

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['query'])) {
    $query = $_GET['query'];
    echo $query; 
}?>
```